# Is it possible to determine what versions of components are in openjdk's rt.jar?

Tags: java

I have a Docker image being scanned by Black Duck Binary Analysis (Protecode). It is reporting that it is unable to determine the version of, for example, xalan. I am guessing that Protecode just "knows" that the openjdk contains xalan classes. I am struggling to determine what version of xalan is included in the rt.jar file. Is there anyway to determine? It is openjdk8u242 in this case, but my question is more of a general one.

Thanks,
Paul